# What is the use of 'preview assets' in XCode 12?

Tags: swiftui, assets

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56512075/9400730) is answered with "it contains assets for the preview canvas", which isn't enough information.

Does the preview assets folder give me any additional power over the preview canvas? If so, how can I utilize it?

Answer (score 1):

> Does the preview assets folder give me any additional power over the preview canvas? If so, how can I utilize it?

`Preview Assets` as it is seen below just by default registered development time only catalog of resources.

So you can store there any images, colors, files, ie any resources, which can be used in Preview Canvas only, for testing purpose. In example to not download one from internet, cloud, or fetch from database. Because Preview is for fast UI-only look & test, so data source is not important, so to test & tune UI you don't need to fetch external data but use locally stored test data.

You can add/name any other development time asset/folder in there as well.

[image: demo2]

[image: demo1]

Comment: How do I load assets from that specific 'preview assets' xcassets file ?

Comment: As you usually load resources from Assets catalog. Eg. if put *test.png* in it then you can create `Image("test")` in preview provider.